# Command with a condition adds white space when written with indentations

Tags: macros, white-space

I have a command that returns a different word according to a predefined value.

```
\def\isPaper{0}
...
\newcommand{\paper}{
    \begingroup
        \def\True{1}
        \ifx\True\isPaper
            paper
        \else
            thesis
        \fi
    \endgroup
}
```

But when I use it, I get an extra white spaces in the text:

```
throughout this \paper.
```

[image: ut this thesis .]

When I remove all formatting and indices and write the whole thing in one line, then the white spaces disappear.

```
\newcommand{\paper}{\begingroup\def\True{1}\ifx\True{\isPaper}paper{\else}thesis\fi\endgroup}
```

Is there a way to keep this command readable and not have the white spaces?

(this happens both when `isPaper` is `0` and `1`)

Comment: put comments `%` to hide the ends of lines, eg `{%` not `{` which is `{SPACE`

Comment: End of line in the source is interpreted as a space character, you need to add `%` at the ends of (at least) line 1, 3, 4, 5, and 7 of the definition. (But that will also mean that you will need to add an explicit space after the macro, i.e. `\paper\ ` since spaces are gobbled after a macro.)  There are also much simpler ways to implement what you're doing here.

Comment: @AlanMunn, what is an example of a simpler way to implement this? I'm with just the basics of Latex.

Comment: @SIMEL One way would be toggles from the etoolbox package.  If you don't want to add any packages, define a boolean: `\newif\ifpaper`, `\papertrue` or `\paperfalse`, and then `\ifpaper paper\else thesis\fi`.

Comment: @Teepeemm, From what I understand it would require more words in the body of the text, which is counter productive. My goal is to have nothing more than `\paper` in the body or at most `{\body}` because of the space issue.

Comment: But you can define `\paper` to be that conditional and use it the same way you're currently using it.  Similarly with etoolbox.  You can keep using `\paper`, but these give you much simpler implementations of your command.

Comment: @Teepeemm, I appreciate the effort, but I am not really sure how to implement this, and I don't see the advantage of this as defining `\paper` to be the conditional still leaves me with the space problem, which is the biggest flaw I see in my implementation. Thank you for your effort nonetheless.